# How do you change a color of an image entirely when hovered in <a> tag element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this example code that hovers an image to change the background color. How do you fill the entire image with color when hovered?

In my code snippet, it only fills the background color of an a tag element but not the image.

Here's an image to further clarify my question.

[image: CartIcon]

How do achieve this using the hover effect in  tag element.

```css
a img:hover {
    background-color: purple;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Hovered with image no text -->
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><img src="cart.png"></a>

<!-- Hovered without image just text -->
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Change color text</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change the CSS background-image property on :hover is the simplex way ... if it is indeed an image - if it is a glyph from some fancy font, then just change CSS background-color property on :hover

Comment: in terms of the image, you can toggle it's `display` CSS property between `none` and `inline`.  If the image is svg, you can color the image itself as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another method to change the background image. I suppose to have two images so when hovered it will change the image. Thanks for the info @Jaromanda X

```css
#my-img:hover {
    content: url('images/pinkcart.png');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<img id="my-img" src="images/redcarticon.png"/>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And thank you also for helping me everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your image is white and the other parts are transparent. Just change the CSS like so:

```css
a img {
    background-color: purple;
}
a:hover img {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Hovered with image no text -->
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><img src="cart.png"></a>

<!-- Hovered without image just text -->
<a href="http://www.wikipedia.org">Change color text</a>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below solution with jQuery:

```css
a img:hover {
    background-color: purple;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<!-- Hovered with image no text -->
<a id='image' href="https://www.w3schools.com"><img src="cart.png"></a>

<!-- Hovered without image just text -->
<a id="text" href="http://www.wikipedia.org" onmouseover="$('#image').css('background-color', 'purple');" onmouseout="$('#image').css('background-color', 'white');">Change color text</a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update style

```
a{
     padding:15px;
     background-color: purple;
     display:block;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```